# Windows 8 Fn key doesn't work for brightness

Tags: windows-8, brightness, fn-key

I have an Asus laptop with Windows 8 and clicking <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> keys (for brightness) doesn't work. In fact, they work, but they can increase/decrease the brightness only one time. What I mean is that after pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> once, nothing happens if I try to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> again, before I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

This only happens after logging in. At the login screen and during Windows boot I can adjust the brightness as I want, but after login I can't.

I installed the latest ATK driver and NVIDIA graphics driver for Windows 8, and I think that my problem is related to conflict with drivers. I tried to reinstall/delete some drivers, but it didn't help.
How can I detect where is the problem?

Comment: What model laptop is it?

Comment: It is Asus K53SJ.

Comment: You could try uninstalling the ATK driver.

Comment: This is probably a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

If keys works before logon, thought you need to check programs which starts **after** logon. Disable them one-by-one and logoff/logon?

You may disable startup programs in Task manager on "Start-up" page.

Comment: Already did. I tried to disable all programms at startup, but it didn't help.

Comment: This might be a driver issue. Make sure you have all the proper drivers for your system's motherboard/chipset installed.